# Can I get the step by step process for downloading images from Google drive using the service account via Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm building a automation test script and I want to overcome the authentication process so that the script doesn't need manual intervention of Tokens getting added during the execution.

I need the step by step process for downloading images from Google drive using the service account via Node.js. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the documentation?  [manage downloads](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#node.js)

```
var fileId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M';
var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/photo.jpg');
drive.files.get({
  fileId: fileId,
  alt: 'media'
})
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Done');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error during download', err);
    })
    .pipe(dest);
```